# Type manipulate in Rust

Tags: rust, types

In C++, we can derive a class from another as following:

```cpp
template<int N> 
struct MyType {
   int arr[N];
};

template<typename T, int E>
struct ModType;

template<int N, int E>
struct ModType<MyType<N>, E> {
   typedef MyType<N+E> extend_type;
};
```

Therefore, using ModType<>, we can derive one data type from another. In Rust, it seems that we can't use `type` inside `struct`. How can we achieve the similar functionality in Rust.

Comment: I would look at how the dimension library works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in stable rust, because arithmetic on const generics isn't stabilized yet.  The nightly feature flag is `generic_const_exprs`.

This is what it would look like on nightly Rust.  Note that the syntax and semantics may change by the time the feature is stabilized.

```
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

struct MyType<const N: usize> {
    arr: [i32; N],
}

struct ModType<T, const E: usize>(std::marker::PhantomData<T>);

trait ModTypeTrait {
    type ExtendType;
}

impl<const N: usize, const E: usize> ModTypeTrait for ModType<MyType<N>, E>
where [(); {N + E}]:
{
    type ExtendType = MyType<{N + E}>;
}
```

This is a straight reimplementation of the given C++ code into Rust. Depending on what problem you're trying to solve with this code, there may be a more Rusty way to approach it.

Comment: Tracking issue for `generic_const_exprs`: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I did a lot of fixed-point simulations in C++. For fixed-point data type, it is usually templated with constant integers. For example, when doing the summation of an array. I usually extend the bit-width of the input array datatype according to the input array length to prevent overflow.